# Need help iterating through a complex Json (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, symfony

I need to create a symfony2 bundle that generates a sidebar from a YAML file

I created this YAML structure

```
Sidebar:
  - Frontpage:
        - Dashboard:
            _icon: 'icon-home'
            _route: 'link'
  - Actions:
          - My_Likes:
              _icon: 'icon-dislike'
              _route: 'link'
          - My_Dislikes:
              _icon: 'icon-home'
              _route: 'link'
  - Interests:
          - Add_Interest:
              _icon: 'icon-home'
              _route: 'link'
```

which returns this JSON as a response.

```
{
  "Sidebar": [
    {
      "Frontpage": [
        {
          "Dashboard": {
            "_icon": "icon-home",
            "_route": "link"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Actions": [
        {
          "My_Likes": {
            "_icon": "icon-dislike",
            "_route": "link"
          }
        },
        {
          "My_Dislikes": {
            "_icon": "icon-home",
            "_route": "link"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Interests": [
        {
          "Add_Interest": {
            "_icon": "icon-home",
            "_route": "link"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using ajax, the json is returned on the 'data' variable on the client side

```
Sidebar.model.request(function(data)
{ 
    for(var a=0; a< data.Sidebar.length; a++ )
    {
       console.log(data.Sidebar[a]);
    }
});
```

I need to find a way to iterate through the parents and find the corresponding children. 
I only need help creating the for loop, so a solution using console.log(data[stuff]); would be enough

---

EDIT: 
here is the adjusted snippet of Daniel Rosano's code

```
    Sidebar.model.request(function(data)
    { 
        //Get Sidebar items
        var SidebarItems = data.Sidebar;

        //Find Categories in Sidebar Items
        for(var a=0; a< SidebarItems.length; a++ )
        {
            var category = SidebarItems[a];

            //Get Category name and append it to sidebar
            var category_name = getSubitemName(category);
            Sidebar.view.renderCategory(category_name);

            //find subitems in categories
            for(var b=0; b < category[category_name].length; b++)
            {
                var button = category[category_name][b];
                var button_name = getSubitemName(button);

                var button_attributes = button[button_name];

                console.log(button_attributes['_icon']);
                Sidebar.view.renderButton(button_name);
            }
        }

        function getSubitemName(parent)
        {
            for(child in parent)
            {
                return child.toString();
            }
        }
    });
```

this is the result, thanks Daniel

[image: Obviously incomplete but this is the result]

Comment: Are the property names such as '"Sidebar"', `"FrontPage"` and `"Dashboard"` and `"_icon"` known in advance (so you can refer to them in your code) or are you looking to iterate whatever arbitrary property names happen to be in your data?

Comment: yes sir, the data may vary. 
Only static data is the Sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need

```
for (var a = 0; a < t.Sidebar.length; a++) {
  var children = t.Sidebar[a];
  for (k in children) {
    var subchild = children[k];
    for (m in subchild) {
      var sschild = subchild[m];
      for (n in sschild) {
         // menu variable has the inner childs (having "_icon" and "_route")
         var menu = sschild[n];
         console.log(menu._icon+ " "+menu._route);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Dan

Comment: Artem Petrosian answer is more correct as he provides a more general solution to the problem.  The above answer also works, but is hard coded to a specific data structure.

Comment: sorry I already solved the problem,  I achieved it by copying and pasting Daniel's Rosanos code and adjusting it accordingly, It'd be extremely unfair to find the solution through his code and not giving him the best answer in this case. Posted the adjusted snippet above.

Comment: @user3531149 -The green checkmark is for the "best answer" (as judged by the person who asked the question).  It's not for the first answer that gives you an idea how to solve the problem.  It's for the best overall answer.  While it does provide a reputation reward to whomever wrote it, the lasting point of the checkmark is so the community and all who view this question in the future can see which answer you thought contained the best information.  It doesn't matter to me which answer you choose, but I thought I should make sure you understood the purpose of the green checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but I had already written this and then got distracted before posting so I thought I'd share it anyway.

It's a recursive iterator that walks through any arrays or objects it finds in whatever you pass in.  It also keeps track of the "path" down to any particular item and the level (mostly for illustrative purposes, but it could be otherwise useful too).  A general purpose iterator that would work for any data passed in, pretty much has to be recursive to handle arbitrary depth.

```
function iterate(item, path, level) {
    level = level || 0;
    path = path || "root";
    if (typeof item === "object") {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            out("iterating array: " + path, level);
            for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                iterate(item[i], path + "[" + i + "]", level + 1);
            }
        } else {
            out("iterating object: " + path, level);
            for (var prop in item) {
                // skip any properties on the prototype
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    iterate(item[prop], path + "." + prop, level + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // leaf level property
        out(path + " = " + item, level);
    }
}
```

Working demo to see how the path and level work: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/k8aosv59/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively:

```
function iterate(obj) {
    console.log(obj);

    for (var key in obj) {

        var items = obj[key];

        for(var i=0,l=items.length;i<l;i++) {
            iterate(items[i]);
        }
    }
}

iterate(data);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jewaee2/)

Comment: Good answer, but I would not use console for output in this case as it will iterate through objects too.  Same as if you just wrote: console.log( data );

Comment: @Robert log is just for demo, obviously, that you can do whatever you want with each node during iteration